# nodejs deployment on aws EC2 issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I try to deploy a simple nodejs app on AWS EC2 server by docker, the server does not respond but the app runs correctly as expected on the local machine by

> docker-compose up -d --build

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    app.use("/api", (req, res) => {
      res.status(200).send("Test Deployment");
    });
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("server runs on port =", port);
    });
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18.13-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production;
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    build: .
    environment:
      PORT: "3000"
    command: npm run start
```

backend container logs on server

```
test-docker$ docker logs backend -f

> test-node@1.0.0 start
> node .

server runs on port = 3000
```

Comment: What does happen when you try to run it?  From a shell on the EC2 instance, can you `curl http://localhost:3000`?  (Do you need to configure AWS security groups, an administration question that might be better asked elsewhere?)

Comment: (You also might consider setting up a Docker Hub or ECR registry and pushing a prebuilt image there, rather than building the image on the target system.)

Comment: thanks for your response i tried `curl localhost:3000/api` and this is the output `Test Deploymen` but when i try `curl http://54.144.145.59:3000/api` i got no response then time limit out